# JVM: JVMJ9VM015W Initialization error for library j9gc28(2): Failed to instantiate compressed references metadata; 200M requested

Tags: http, java, ibm-domino, jvm

I am getting the following errors on the IBM Domino Server console.
Running 9.0.1 FP8 Win64

- HTTP Server: Using Web Configuration View
- HTTP JVM: JVMJ9VM015W Initialization error for library j9gc28(2): Failed to instantiate compressed references metadata; 200M requested
- JVM: The Java Virtual Machine creation returned an invalid JVM machine pointer.
- JVM: Java Virtual Machine failed to start
- HTTP Server: Error Loading Java Virtual Machine
- HTTP Server: JVM: Missing entrypoint in JVM runtime library.
- HTTP Server: Shutdown

I have tried different settings 
HTTPJVMMAXHEAPSIZE=1024M, HTTPJVMMAXHEAPSIZE=128M, HTTPJVMMAXHEAPSIZE=512M,

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried adding M after the requested value to see if that helps? So for instance: HTTPJVMMAXHEAPSIZE=1024M

Comment: I use an "M" but forgot to type it in the post, I will update the post